# Permission denied for ttyACM0 Port in nexus 5

Tags: external, modem, ril

I am trying to connect external GSM modem with nexus 5 and send AT command using android RIL layer.I am using android 5.0 AOSP for nexus 5 downloaded from Google source.

Error: Permission denied with trying to open ttyACM0 port.
i have checked this by changing permissions but still permission denied error.

Does there any other permissions do i have to change to open port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting permission denied because the Android RIL doesn't have the appropriate [selinux(Security Enhanced Linux)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) permissions for that device.
As the RIL already has rw permissions to the files in the **radio_device** context as shown below and in [this](https://code.google.com/p/aosp-bluez/source/browse/rild.te?repo=external-sepolicy&r=fee49159e760162b0e8ee5a4590c50a65b8e322f&spec=svn.external-sepolicy.7de19397988796006d55cc32f198c694f0d33f76) link.

```
allow rild radio_device:chr_file rw_file_perms;
```

So, just change the context of your device file to `radio_device` so that the RIL has the appropriate permissions to access it by adding the line below to file `YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY/external/sepolicy/file_context` and hopefully it should work.

```
/dev/ttyACM0        u:object_r:radio_device:s0
```