# Neither user nor current process has android.permission.SERIAL_PORT

Tags: android, serial-port, baud-rate

I have gotten my hands on a Android POS device and I am currently trying to make our company's app work on the machine. a POS Z90 device.

at one point I must the set the devName and baudRate (according to the example given)

```
handler.setParameters("/dev/ttyS2", 115200);
```

when i run:

```
handler.connect()
```

which calls:

```
this.mSerialPort = this.mSerialManager.openSerialPort(this.devName, this.baudrate);
```

I get the following android permission exception:

> Neither user (#number) nor current process has android.permission.SERIAL_PORT.

So my question is how can i add the needed permission?

background:

> minSdkVersion 19
>
> targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @sultan No sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add user permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT"

Comment: The permission is not listed in the predefined  android permissions list and when I just add it anyway, the exception still gets thrown, so weird

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742524/why-cant-i-open-write-from-a-serial-port-on-android

Comment: Maybe it will be useful